# Install cyanogenmod on an S5 mini (G800F)

Tags: cyanogenmod

probably a standard question. I would like to install cyanogenmod on my device. There is a ROM [available](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5-mini/development/g800f-cyanogenmod-12-1-g800f-t3083493) which I would like to try. I can boot my device into recovery mode. I can choose to flash the zip to be flashed, I do however get the "E: failed to verify whole-file signature" error, presumably because the image is not signed by Samsung.

1. To get around this problem, is it necessary to install TWRP / CWM or is there another way to flash the image?
2. Is TWRP/CWM device-dependent as well?
3. If yes, where can I find an image suitable for my device (I don't want to hard-brick the device by getting the wrong one)?
4. The link above mentions a recovery image. However, this image has a *.md5 extension and not *.img. Isn't the latter required (at least for odin3 / heimdall)?

Answer (score 1):

1. 3rd-party recovery is necessary.
2. Yes.
3. XDA-Developers also have you covered. You already have the ROM there, why not take some more time to look around and grab [TWRP 3.0.0](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5-mini/orig-development/recovery-twrp-3-0-0-t3313775) (newer than provided in your link)?
4. *.md5 allows Odin/Heimdall to verify image integrity before loading it. It's just your regular *.tar with MD5 attached to it. Odin does not accept *.imgs.

Also, in case you didn't notice, [CyanogenMod 13](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5-mini/development/g800f-m-y-cyanogenmod-13-0-g800f-m-y-t3234909) is available for this device too.